# Copy to same column twice in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy data from S3 to Redshift. The data in S3 is in this format :-

```
23~2~wanted~210
```

and I want it to be updated to a table in Redshift which has 3 columns.

```
COPY table1(col1, col2, col3, col2) from 's3://bucket' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws' delimiter '~' dateformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
GZIP   NULL AS 'x000' REMOVEQUOTES;
```

But this is not working. I want to update the later value to col2. Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load 2 values to the same column. You'd have to do that in a second query after the load completes.